# stringi functions within dplyr

Tags: r, stringi

I wanted to modify the method in another post ([Reading in Unicode Emoji correctly into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675990/reading-in-unicode-emoji-correctly-into-r)), to check if a unicode string corresponds to an emoji... but I obviously haven't quite grasped how to use stringi correctly.

The first section of code is a simplification of the linked post and works as expected; with first and last entries being replaced:

```
a <- c("\U0001f600",       "\U0001f603",       "\U0001f604")
b <- c("grinning face", "grinning face with big eyes", "grinning face with smiling eyes" )

v <- data.frame(lemma = c("\U0001f600",  "\U0001f3fb", "hello", "asdfasdlkasdfkd", "\U0001f604"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
v %>% mutate(is_emoji = stri_replace_all_regex(lemma,
                       pattern = a,
                       replacement = b,
                       vectorize_all=FALSE))
```

But my attempt to return a boolean does not; in addition to an warning message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length", I am not getting the last value equal to TRUE with the following code:

```
v %>% mutate(is_emoji = stri_detect_regex(lemma, pattern = a))
```

I have tried countless other variation but all with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` with `collapse='|'`

```
v %>% mutate(is_emoji = stri_detect_regex(lemma, pattern = paste(a, collapse = '|')))
```